# problema com if else no javascript dentro do ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

e um controle de seleção para o checkbox então se for apenas um funciona normal porem se tiver tipo 2 opção... uma de escolher 3 sabores e outra de escolher 2 sabores se eu selecionar primeiro o de 3 vai normal e quando eu clico no de escolher um sabor tbm mais se eu apertar em escolher novamente o de 3 ele continua funcionando como se fosse a de 2... mais a variavel controler e a variavel maximopermitido estão com os valores corretos eu n entendo o porque o if e else faz isso... deve ser algum armazenamento n sei... vou postar o codigo

obs: em imputs radios eu seleciono quantos sabores escolher para poder funcionar o código que vou postar ai agora... obrigado quem puder ajudar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $('.tamanho_item').click(function (){
            var vaaloridtamahoclick = $(this).data('idtaamanho');
            var iddoitem = $(this).data('iddoitem');
            var iddacategoria = $(this).data('iddacategoria');

            $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);

            $('#id_checkbox'+iddoitem).prop("checked", true);
            $('#id_checkbox'+iddoitem).prop("disabled", true);

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?=$site;?>controlers/mostrar-meioameio.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: {'iditem' : iddoitem, 'idcat' : iddacategoria, 'idoption' : vaaloridtamahoclick, 'userid' : '<?=$getu;?>'},
                success:function(data){
                    var maximopermitido = data;
                    var totalselecionagroup = data - 1;

                    if(data > 0){
                        $('#valortotalint_'+iddoitem).text(totalselecionagroup);
                        $("#mostrarmeioameio_"+iddoitem).show();
                        
                        $('#cf_group_meioameio'+iddoitem+' input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
                            
                            var controle = $('#cf_group_meioameio' + iddoitem + ' input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
                            //$('#valortotalint_'+iddoitem).text(controle + ' --> ' + maximopermitido);
                            
                            if(controle > maximopermitido){
                                $(this).prop('checked', '');
                                $(this).addClass("tremer");
                                $('.hcinco').addClass("tremer");

                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    $('input[type=checkbox]').removeClass("tremer");
                                    $('.hcinco').removeClass("tremer");
                                }, 1000);

                            }

                        });     

                    }else{
                        $("#mostrarmeioameio_"+iddoitem).hide();
                    }   
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```